# Copying two <p> produces a blank line; copying <h1> elements doesn't

Tags: html, css, chromium

So, if we select and copy two paragraphs sitting next to each other, and then paste it in the text editor, there will be a blank line between them. If we do the same but with any other block elements, e.g. headers, there's no blank line. Why is it happening and how can I achieve this behaviour on other block elements?

**Code (paragraphs):**

```html
<p>first paragraph</p>
<p>second paragraph</p>
```

**Result (paragraphs):**

```
> first paragraph
> 
> second paragraph
```

**Code (other elements):**

```html
<h3>first paragraph</h3>
<h3>second paragraph</h3>
```

**Result (other elements):**

```
> first paragraph
> second paragraph
```

Notice, there's no blank line between the lines in the second result.

```css
textarea {
  width: 30em;
  height: 10em;
}
```

```html
<h3>Select and copy these four lines of text</h3>
<div>Paste into the textarea below</div>
<p>There is a blank line after the P element</p>
<h4>What causes this?</h4>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: This looks more like a question about code editors than about HTML/CSS.

Comment: I edited your question to include a reproducible snippet

Comment: ```p``` is consider as **block level element** therefore it will add space/new line. If you don't want ```p``` to have a new line, set its property from *block* to *inline*. So you can do ```p{ display: inline; }``` in your css.

Comment: @Newbee The OP wants to know how to control whether or not a new line is added after a block element when it is selected and copied into a plain text field.

Comment: Are you asking how the elements are _rendered_? I don't think I'm following. When I copy+paste the HTML, there are no extra lines added. When I copy+paste, there's no blank line after the paragraph (but there is one _before_ the paragraph, i.e. after the div).

Comment: It doesn't happen to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing in the Standard specifies how the selection in the rendered DOM should be converted to plain text, so this depends entirely on the application you copy from and/or the one you "paste" in.

There is [3.2.7 The innerText and outerText properties](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-innertext-idl-attribute) which says:

> 8. If node is a `p` element, then append 2 (a required line break count) at the beginning and end of items.

But that is only relevant if you use `.innerText` or `.outerText`; however, this is not considered if the selection in the rendered DOM is converted to plain text because CSS there can affect the spacing or if there are new lines at all.

A clipboard can hold multiple representations of the data you copied.

On "paste" the application will check the clipboard for the best matching representation for the target (or on the desired behavior the user chooses for insert), and converts the data if necessary (with its own rules)

In JavaScript, you can overwrite what is stored in the clipboard upon copy:

```js
function copyListener(event) {
  event.clipboardData.setData("text/html", "here we have <strong>html</strong>");
  event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", 'this is just plain text');
  event.preventDefault();

};

document.addEventListener("copy", copyListener, false);
```

```css
.editor {
  width: 30em;
  height: 10em;
  border: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200)
}
```

```html
<p>copy me</p>
<p>
  Paste as Plain:
</p>
<textarea class="editor"></textarea>
<p>
  Paste as HTML:
</p>
<div contenteditable class="editor">
</div>
```

So as you can see here, something completely different to "copy me" is saved in the clipboard, and depending on whether you "paste" it to `<textarea>` or `contenteditable` you get the corresponding data.

This is also the case (for many applications and OSs) if you "paste" it into a different application. If you paste it "normally" it a RTE it would use the HTML version, or if you choose "Paste as plain text" or "Paste and Match style" which would use "text/plain". If no "text/plain" is present, it is up to the application that performs the paste to decide how to format it.

So if you want to have something consistent for the plain text you could use the `html` as is and then just overwrite the `text/plain` with your own converted text.

```js
function copyListener(event) {
  const range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  const rangeContents = range.cloneContents();
  const wrapper =  document.createElement('div')
  wrapper.appendChild(rangeContents);

  // store the actual HTML for rich text editors
  event.clipboardData.setData("text/html", wrapper.innerHTML);

  // store some custome plain text
  event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", 'my custom plain text');
  
  event.preventDefault();
};


document.addEventListener("copy", copyListener, false);
```

```css
.editor {
  width: 30em;
  height: 10em;
  border: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200)
}
```

```html
<h3>Select and copy these four lines of text</h3>
<div>Paste into the textarea below</div>
<p>There is a blank line after the P element</p>
<h4>What causes this?</h4>


<p>
  Paste as Plain:
</p>
<textarea class="editor"></textarea>
<p>
  Paste as HTML:
</p>
<div contenteditable class="editor">
</div>
```

Comment: This issue is observed on Chromium (copying in Brave browser, pasting in VSCode). I had to debug chromium source code to get to the bottom of this, which led me to this: https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/f69fefeb8dd8173e43be8de560b1a8b6be9a6614/third_party/blink/renderer/core/editing/iterators/text_iterator.cc#L697-L705. Turns out, Chromium here actually relies on the standard for innerText/outerText: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-innertext-idl-attribute

Comment: The standard reads:

`§ 3.2.7...8: If node is a p element, then append 2 (a required line break count) at the beginning and end of items.` Since it's part of the standard, I presume it won't be considered a bug, but I don't really understand the reason behind inserting double newline there. Is there a way to see when a specific clause has been added to the standard? I also think that it may not be correct to rely on this standard when copying text, but maybe I'm not seeing something, chromium codebase is quite big...

Comment: @RamanSinclair Update the answer. The `§ 3.2.7` is only about `innerText`, `outerText` without considering CSS.  But how the content described by HTML is rendered is heavily influenced by CSS. So the Standard would need to describe how - also considering the CSS - the selected text has to be converted to plain text.

Comment: Yes, as I said this bit of standard seems irrelevant to Clipboard manipulation, but it looks like this is what Chromium relies on when writing rich content into the Plain Text clipboard buffer. If I'm reading it right, this doesn't have to be the case. I'll try to raise an issue with the Chromium project, let's see what the team says. Meanwhile, I'll accept this answer, since it helped me to understand in which direction to dig.

Comment: @RamanSinclair If you learned more about that and gained more in-depth knowledge, feel free to write your own answer and accept that one.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! I actually didn't have time to follow this up, but I guess at some point I will.